# I don't know endsWith in javascript work like this and more1111

Tags: javascript

```js
const str = 'Do. Or do not. There is no try.';
console.log(str.endsWith('try', 30)); //true 
console.log(str.endsWith('try.', 30)); //false
```

Can anyone explain why in example 2 it is false. I think it is similar with above and must return true?

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of the second argument in [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) (or something else reputable)? That's the first thing to do in this kind of situation. In this case, it would tell you the answer. If you only look at the end of the first 30 characters of `"Do. Or do not. There is no try."`, you see it ends with `try`, not `try.`. The 30 says "pretend the string is only that long, ignore the rest."

Comment: If you do not set the second parameter, its default value is the total length of the string, and when you set it, it will be compared with the value you set

Answer (score 1):

Because in [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the second parameter is `length`.
The string

```
Do. Or do not. There is no try.
```

is `31` characters long, by setting the length parameter to `30`, you're only testing

```
Do. Or do not. There is no try
```

which does not end with `try.`

As [Ian said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234444/i-dont-know-endswith-in-javascript-work-like-this-and-more1111#comment125914975_71234444), you can omit the `length` parameter to test the entire string:

```
const str = 'Do. Or do not. There is no try.';
console.log(str.endsWith('try'));  // false
console.log(str.endsWith('try.')); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `y` is the 30th character, and in the `length` parameter of the function call you've specified it should test the ending of the first 30 characters of the string. Therefore it doesn't take the `.` (which is the 31st character) into account.

You're actually only testing the following text:

> Do. Or do not. There is no try

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith